# how to compare date from table in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I am using field type varchar for date: `d-m-Y H:i:s`
my query is here:

```
$todaydate=date('d-m-Y')
select id from  table where id=$id and str_to_date(date, '%d-%m-%Y')='$todaydate'
```

I used this query but i didn't get result,can you people please help me to solve this issue

Comment: What values do you want to get from the table?

Comment: only current date matched records

Comment: select id from table where id=$id and date like ('$todaydate%')

Comment: Rafael Shkembi thank you its working.

Comment: Store dates properly

Answer (score 1):

Please use below code to you can fetch record from database using date where filter.

> 

```
$todaydate=date('Y-m-d');
select id from  table where id=$id and DATE(date)='.$todaydate.'
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case a mysql `'like'` operator could do the trick.
As you said in your table you have a date column and the values saved are like this 03-09-2016 09:25:22 . Now you want to take all the values in your table based on date not the time.

```
$todaydate=date('Y-m-d'); //this will give 03-09-2016
select id from table where id=$id and date like ('$todaydate%')
```

In your query you are taking all the values that beggin with `03-09-2016` and ends in whatever value you have saved.